# Is it possible to create a personal website which adheres to CPRA, CCPA and GDPR?

Tags: web-hosting, privacy

I would like to build a static website which basically represents a portfolio/resume which doesn't use cookies or third-party analytics and only has a `mailto://` for email.

It seems very difficult to find a web host which easily allows me to just have a few static web pages without needing to go through a lengthy understanding of how the CPRA vs CCPA vs GDPR works and what I need to include in a privacy policy or terms and conditions. To make things even more confusing, the web host would most likely have their own analytics or IP logging and so you also need to understand how that affects your website and what you need to explain to the website visitor.

Has anyone had similar issues with this, or have any recommendations on what the best course of action would be to host a very basic website?

Comment: It's probably not wise to gather legal advice from Internet strangers. In addition to that, software or service recommendations are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow since they tend to attract just opinions and sometimes spam. With that being said, you might try to find a webhoster which allows to disable any server logs and allows you to upload your own HTML files.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is for programming questions, not legal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not collecting any personal data, GDPR simply doesn't apply, so it's not too difficult to avoid problems.

If you don't use shared hosting, but use a dedicated VM (typical costs start from about €3/month) and configure HTTPS, then your visitors will not be seen by your hosting provider in any meaningful sense beyond encrypted TCP traffic. On your VM you can either turn off logging altogether, or retain basic IP logging on the basis of legitimate interests, which is entirely defensible for security and anti-abuse purposes, though if you're only serving static pages you may as well not bother.

Even if you're serving only static pages, loading client-side content from third party sources can present a problem, so avoid using anything like JS library or image CDNs, Google fonts, analytics, tag manager, anything from facebook, twitter, instagram, etc, though linking *to* those places is fine. Set very strict CSP and secure referrer-policy headers and don't use any cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro for your comment. Fortunately the site would not contain any external JS files, cookies etc - everything would be sourced from the website host. I know that a shared hosting plan means several customers having their own 'space' on the server for their websites, but if it's possible for the customer to turn off logging on their 'space' I presume that would also work? When you mention dedicated VM, is that similar to dedicated cloud VPS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using VM and VPS interchangeably. You get a whole server and root access, nobody else has access, nothing is shared (other than hypervisor host resources). On good ones you can also encrypt your volumes which would mean that even your hosting provider can't access your data.